# Expresion regular para hacer match en un grupo de palabras separadas por un espacio

Tags: regex, perl

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
while (<DATA>){
        chomp();
        if (/^(\s+|)(\d+)\s+(\S+|\S+\s|\s\S+\s)+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)/) {
                print "<$2> \t <$3> \t <$4> \n";
        }
}

__DATA__
 N NAME                                     SERIAL        STATUS    POWER   STATUS2
 2 SERV123 NX                               FF283G01VN      OK       On      Off
 3 SERV127                                    HSSD9G01VN      OK       On      Off
 5 SERV121.domain.com                              XSF4J1H68P      OK       On      Off
 6 SERV3a21.domain.com                           XHE4G1F69W      OK       On      Off
 7 NONE
 8 SERV nodomain present                      5H2190HK2      OK       On      Off
 9 SERV537.domain.com                            JGD4JKL65X      OK       On      Off
```

Para extraer los datos, uso esta expresión regular:

```
^(\s+|)(\d+)\s+(\S+|\S+\s|\s\S+\s)+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

La expresión deja de funcionar en el número 2 "SERV123 NX" y el número 8 "SERV nodomain present", **que no tiene puntos** y **está separado por un espacio**. Intenté usar esta regexp "(\S+|\S+\s|\s\S+\s)" pero no funciona. Esta es la salida actual:

```
<2>      < NX >                  <On>   <-- No funciona la regexp
<3>      <SERV127>               <On>
<5>      <SERV121.domain.com>    <On>
<6>      <SERV3a21.domain.com>   <On>
<8>      <present>               <On>   <-- No funciona la regexp
<9>      <SERV537.domain.com>    <On>
```

Y esta es la salida que necesito:

```
<2>      <SERV123 NX>               <On>   <-- Lo que se espera de salida
<3>      <SERV127>                  <On>
<5>      <SERV121.domain.com>       <On>
<6>      <SERV3a21.domain.com>      <On>
<8>      <SERV nodomain present>    <On>   <-- Lo que se espera de salida
<9>      <SERV537.domain.com>       <On>
```

A considerar: En el campo NAME, solo aparecerá nombres de dominios o nombres con algunas palabras separada por un espacio.

¿Qué me falta? Aprecio la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente expresión regular se puede resolver:

```perl
while (<DATA>){
    if (/(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+[A-Z0-9]+\s+OK\s+(O(?:n|ff))/) {
        print "<$1>\t<$2>\t<$3>\n";
    }
}
```

El chomp() no es necesario por que los caracteres de fin de línea no influyen en el patrón ni vamos a capturar el último campo.

Hay que usar los paréntesis para la captura de lo que queremos obtener, o usar la expresión `(?:...)` que sirve para agrupar expresiones que no deseemos capturar.

El patrón es:

`(\d+)` La clave principal de las líneas que queremos capturar es que debe empezar por un número, así que eso es justo lo que ponemos al principio del patrón, además de capturarlo.

`\s+` Los campos están separados por grupos de espacios.

`(.+?)` Capturamos cualquier cosa, pero solo hasta que se cumple la siguiente parte del patrón. Esta es la parte más ineficiente y que se puede optimizar más adelante.

`[A-Z0-9]+` Luego viene un grupo de letras mayúsculas y dígitos, que no capturamos.

`OK` Hemos supuesto que la columna STATUS debe estar siempre a "OK".

`(O(?:n|ff))` Y finalmente viene la palabra "On" u "Off", que capturamos.

El patrón no es eficiente por culpa de ".+?", realizando varias vueltas atrás, sobre todo cuando el campo NAME contiene espacios.

Si se quiere una mayor eficiencia, se podría indicar el ancho del campo, con cuantificadores, por ejemplo: `(.{32})` para capturar siempre un campo de 32 caracteres de ancho. Más tarde, con otra expresión regular se pueden quitar los espacios extra.

```perl
while (<DATA>){
    if (my ($N, $NAME, $POWER) = /(\d+) \s+ (.{32}) \s+ [A-Z0-9]+ \s+ OK \s+ (O(?:n|ff))/x) {
        $NAME =~ s/\s+$//;
        print "<$N>\t<$NAME>\t<$POWER>\n";
    }
}
```

Otra opción es saber si los campos están separados con caracteres de tabulación, por lo que se simplifica el patrón aún más.

Comment: El primer campo es fijo, pero el resto de los campos pueden venir con espacios de más y no usa tabulaciones. 
Pero encontré una mejor manera de hacerlo, usando esta expresión:  

`/(\d+)\s+((?:[\S]+\s)*)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)/`

Con esta regexp, agrega un espacio adicional al final del campo "NAME", que se resuelve con otra regexp que elimina el espacio final.